# Open UI5 sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, sapui5

I've been trying to get started on building OpenUI5 apps using cordova. The latest issue I am facing is that I can't seem to use my local "resources" folder (where all the OpenUI5 js files are stored). I am running the index.html file on chrome with web security disabled to allow for cross platform calls (as I was getting an error for that when running it on chrome in normal mode).

I even tried running the index.html page using http-server, but that wouldn't display the page, instead only downloading it whenever I tried to access it on the browser.

Now when I try to load the page, chrome's developer tools gives me [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmT2Z.png).

The html page has virtually no code. All I am trying to do is open up a blank page with the title "Hello World".

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <!-- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com -->
    <!-- https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com -->
    <script  src= "./resources/sap-ui-core.js"
       id= "sap-ui-bootstrap"
       data-sap-ui-libs= "sap.m"
       data-sap-ui-theme= "sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="content" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any solution as to how I can proceed would be highly appreciated.

***PS: The library js files seem to work fine when accessed using the openui5.hana.ondemand.com/ or sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/ urls in place of "./resources/"***

***PPS: The issue persists on the android emulator as well, so it's not a browser issue, I think.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see [there](http://openui5.org/download.html)  openui resources library. Take this resources file your www folder. And ı am using **../resources/sap-ui-core.js** maybe help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run your Sample project in SAP web IDE, In the **index.html** file of your project, look for the line

**src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"**

Make it ---->

**src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"**

This solved my issue. Let me know any other way worked for you.

I

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately core-ui is just one of the files that you need for OpenUI5.

If using Windows, and due to errors apparently you are, Chrome will not load other Javascript parts from a javascript file. So you needs a Web Server like Apache. Or you can try put this on your Chrome shortcut destination: "C:\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files file:///C:/OpenUI5/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
src= "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
id= "sap-ui-bootstrap"
data-sap-ui-libs= "sap.m"
data-sap-ui-theme= "sap_bluecrystal"
```

or

```
src= "resources/sap-ui-core.js"
id= "sap-ui-bootstrap"
data-sap-ui-libs= "sap.m"
data-sap-ui-theme= "sap_bluecrystal">
```